# Django CheckboxSelectMultiple not rendering as list

Tags: django

I have a field courses which needs to be rendered as list( CheckboxSelectMultiple renders items as list)-

```
teacher_courses = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Course.objects.all().order_by('name'),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        required=False,
    )
```

From Django docs:-

```
CheckboxSelectMultiple¶

class CheckboxSelectMultiple[source]¶
Similar to SelectMultiple, but rendered as a list of check buttons:

<ul>
  <li><input type='checkbox' name='...' ></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

but when my form(im using crispy forms) its not being rendered as a unordered list, instead as labels

[image]

Here is my crispy form layout --

```
Div(
                HTML('''<p>What courses or topics do you currently teach?</p>'''),                
                Field('teacher_courses')
                ,css_class = 'box add hidden-xs teacher-fields form-group'
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is the [default template crispy ships for this FormField](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/blob/dev/crispy_forms/templates/bootstrap3/layout/checkboxselectmultiple.html) - at least for all the bootstrap template packs. As they ship their own, this shadows the django docs.